# Vue2 Export SVG element to download as a file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, vuejs2, vue-component

This [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqdXxv)  downloads an *SVG* as a file using pur javacript. I want to do this with `Vue.js`. I have an svg, one attribute of which, the `radius`, is bound to the vue instances data and is dynamically controlled via a slider. I would like to be able to download the current svg element as an svg file at any time by clicking a button.

The template,

```
<svg id="dynamicIllustration" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="200">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="lightblue" />
<circle cx="150" cy="100" :r="radius" fill="lightgreen" />
<text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="gray">SVG</text>
</svg>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="downloadSVG()">Download SVG</button>
<input style="display: inline-block;" type="range" min="0" max="100" width="100" class="form-control-range sliderSize" v-model="radius" id="formControlRange">
```

How do i write the method to do this with vue?

```
  downloadSVG(){
        console.log("running downloadSVG()");
        // document.querySelector(".link-download").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    const svgContent = document.getElementById("dynamicIllustration").outerHTML,
          blob = new Blob([svgContent], {
              type: "image/svg+xml"
          }),
          url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob),
          link = evt.target;

    link.target = "_blank";
    link.download = "Illustration.svg";
    link.href = url;
// });

      },
```

One line is commented out because the click event is already handled by vue. As a result I don't have an `evt` and that's what the error tells me when I try to run it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vue will pass the event automatically to your click handler

```
  <a href="#" @click="downloadSVG" class="link-download btn btn-primary btn-sm">Download displayed SVG</a>
```

You just need to receive it in your method like this :

```
    downloadSVG(evt){....
```

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    radius: 10
  },
  methods: {
    downloadSVG(evt) {


      const svgContent = document.getElementById("dynamicIllustration").outerHTML,
        blob = new Blob([svgContent], {
          type: "image/svg+xml"
        })
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      let link = evt.target;

      link.target = "_blank";
      link.download = "Illustration1.svg";
      link.href = url;
      let body = document.querySelector('body')
      body.appendChild(link)
      link.click()
      console.log(link)

    }

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />



<div id="app" class="container">
  <svg id="dynamicIllustration" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="200">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="lightblue" />
<circle cx="150" cy="100" :r="radius" fill="lightgreen" />
<text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="gray">SVG</text>
</svg>
  <a href="#" @click="downloadSVG" class="link-download btn btn-primary btn-sm">Download displayed SVG</a>

  <input style="display: inline-block;" type="range" min="0" max="100" width="100" class="form-control-range sliderSize" v-model="radius" id="formControlRange">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  methods: {
    downloadSVG(data: any, idx: number) {
      const svg_data: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById(
        `myData${idx}`
      );

      const x = svg_data?.outerHTML;

      const svgBlob = new Blob([x as BlobPart], {
        type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8",
      });

      saveAs(svgBlob, `${data.title}.svg`);
    },
  },
```

```html
<div v-for="(data, idx) in 5" :key="idx">

  <button
    @click="downloadSVG(data, idx)"
  >
    Download
  </button>

  <svg
    :id="`myData${idx}`"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    color="#131214"
    fill="none"
    style="width: 75px; height: 75px;">
    <path
      d="M8.8 13L11.8586 15.6904C11.8976 15.7301 11.9488 15.75 12 15.75M15.2 13L12.1414 15.6904C12.1024 15.7301 12.0512 15.75 12 15.75M12 15.75C12 12.4696 12 8.25 12 8.25M20 12C20 16.4183 16.4183 20 12 20C7.58172 20 4 16.4183 4 12C4 7.58172 7.58172 4 12 4C16.4183 4 20 7.58172 20 12Z"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="round"
      stroke-width="6%"
      stroke="#131214"
      fill="none">
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

this is how to make an svg download function with nuxt2 vue2 with typescript

first of all

create handle click on the download button with the function name downloadSVG() which sends the data parameter, and index

then the function is declared with typescript
data:any, idx:number

then the svg_data varriable is declared as HTMMLElement | null
why is there null because the contents of the svg_data variable must be empty alias null

then filled with the command document.getElementById which we have marked in the svg tag, namely `myData${idx}`

then declare variable x which is filled with the variable svg_data then check with the command ? then .outerHTML
why should it be checked because it returns to the initial step if the contents of the svg data variable are HTMLElement | null

then the results of the above conversion are entered into the svgBlob variable and don't forget to declare variable x as BlopPart, with type "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"

then saveAs svgBlob, with the file name you want to custom, if I take it from the title/alt name

oh yeah, I downloaded the saveAs function first to the npm package in this documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver and imported it above so that no errors occur

thanks hope it helps